# Проблемы со смещенным border на картинке с hover-ом

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно сделать картинки-ссылки которые становятся цветными при наведении на них и меняет цвет бордер. Проблема в том что бордер смещенный и идет backgraund-ом.
HTML

```css
` .btn-main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-main-content a {
  color: #01983b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-btn img {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.img-btn img:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.img-btn img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  filter: none;
  border: 5px solid #0079db;
}

.img-btn a:hover {
  color: #0079db;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-main-content">
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-1.png" alt="Виды работ">балконы и лоджии</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-2.png" alt="Виды работ">Lorem ipsum.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-3.png" alt="Виды работ">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-4.png" alt="Виды работ">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-5.png" alt="Виды работ">Lorem ipsum.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-btn">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ic_btn-6.png" alt="Виды работ">lorem</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если менять сами картинки при наведении?

Comment: @ Денис, мне бы тоже этого хотелось, но нужно именно таким путем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тэга img нет before/after, посему нужен оборачивающий тэг, далее просто вешаем блок с border в ::after :

```css
.btn-main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-main-content a {
  color: #01983b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-btn .img-container img {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  }
 .img-btn .img-container {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-btn:hover .img-container::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 5px);
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
  z-index: 100;
  top: -2.5px;
  left: -2.5px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #0079db;
}


.img-btn:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  filter: none;
  display: block;

}

.img-btn a:hover {
  color: #0079db;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-main-content">
  <div class="img-btn"><a href="#">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000?text=01" alt=""></div>lorem01
    </a></div>
  <div class="img-btn"><a href="#">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000?text=02" alt=""></div>lorem02
    </a></div>
  <div class="img-btn"><a href="#">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000?text=03" alt=""></div>lorem03
    </a></div>
  <div class="img-btn"><a href="#">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000?text=04" alt=""></div>lorem04
    </a></div>
  <div class="img-btn"><a href="#">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000?text=05" alt=""></div>lorem05
    </a></div>
</div>
```

ps: лучше делать примеры с плейсхолдерами

Comment: @ Добрый день, проблема не решается. И более того странно, но при просмотре в инспекторе after не реагирует на какие то изменения в нем и не отображается в элементах.

Comment: не очень понял, в моём сниппете работает ?

Comment: @ нет, изменений вообще нет(

Comment: исправил, чтобы работало везде, вставил плейсхолдеры, чтобы было понятно что именно не работает.

Comment: @ вот что выходит....
.https://pp.userapi.com/c836738/v836738512/3519e/ZZNA_3Rx7EE.jpg
Еще проблема в том что ромбики разной формы, скорее всего картинки влияют на это.

Comment: вставил вендорные префиксы и начало работать. Остался последний вопрос, как сделать что бы рамка была еще постоянно но другим цветом?

Comment: ну так же как и в :hover просто без hover :)